# kurier font not displaying in math mode

Tags: fonts, math-mode

I'm trying to change the default font of my document to Kurier.  The main text is showing up fine, as well as any special characters.  However, when I enter math mode and type an equation it's using a serif font for the operators instead.

I use the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[math]{kurier}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
    y = \exp ( \cos x + \sin x )
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

In this example, exp, cos and sin all appear in serif font.  The rest appears in Kurier.  What am I doing wrong?

This is my log file:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-1.40.11 (TeX Live 2010/MacPorts 2010_4) (format=pdflatex 2011.6.9)  25 JUN 2012 21:18
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**test
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2009/09/24>
Babel <v3.8l> and hyphenation patterns for english, dumylang, nohyphenation, cz
ech, slovak, dutch, ukenglish, usenglishmax, basque, french, german-x-2009-06-1
9, ngerman-x-2009-06-19, german, ngerman, swissgerman, italian, polish, portugu
ese, spanish, catalan, galician, loaded.
(/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count79
\c@section=\count80
\c@subsection=\count81
\c@subsubsection=\count82
\c@paragraph=\count83
\c@subparagraph=\count84
\c@figure=\count85
\c@table=\count86
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
)
(/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
Package: fontenc 2005/09/27 v1.99g Standard LaTeX package

(/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive-dist/tex/latex/base/t1enc.def
File: t1enc.def 2005/09/27 v1.99g Standard LaTeX file
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding T1 on input line 43.
))
(/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive-dist/tex/latex/kurier/kurier.sty
Package: kurier 2005/10/03 v.1.2 Kurier package (MW)
\c@mv@kurier=\count87
\c@mv@kurierbold=\count88
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `kurier'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/n --> OT1/kurierm/m/n on input line 59.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `letters' in version `kurier'
(Font)                  OML/cmm/m/it --> OML/kurier/m/it on input line 60.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `symbols' in version `kurier'
(Font)                  OMS/cmsy/m/n --> OMS/kurier/m/n on input line 61.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `largesymbols' in version `kurier'
(Font)                  OMX/cmex/m/n --> OMX/kurier/m/n on input line 62.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `kurierbold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/n --> OT1/kurierm/b/n on input line 63.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `letters' in version `kurierbold'
(Font)                  OML/cmm/m/it --> OML/kurier/b/it on input line 64.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `symbols' in version `kurierbold'
(Font)                  OMS/cmsy/m/n --> OMS/kurier/b/n on input line 65.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `largesymbols' in version `kurierbold'
(Font)                  OMX/cmex/m/n --> OMX/kurier/b/n on input line 66.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathbf' in version `kurier'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/n --> OT1/kurier/bx/n on input line 68.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathsf' in version `kurier'
(Font)                  OT1/cmss/m/n --> OT1/kurier/m/n on input line 69.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathit' in version `kurier'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/it --> OT1/kurier/m/it on input line 70.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathtt' in version `kurier'
(Font)                  OT1/cmtt/m/n --> OT1/kurier/m/n on input line 71.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathsf' in version `kurierbold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmss/m/n --> OT1/kurier/bx/n on input line 72.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathit' in version `kurierbold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/it --> OT1/kurier/bx/it on input line 73.
)
No file test.aux.
\openout1 = `test.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for T1+cmss on input line 8.
(/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive-dist/tex/latex/base/t1cmss.fd
File: t1cmss.fd 1999/05/25 v2.5h Standard LaTeX font definitions
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for OT1+kurierm on input line 
10.
LaTeX Font Info:    No file OT1kurierm.fd. on input line 10.


LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OT1/kurierm/m/n' undefined
(Font)              using `OT1/cmr/m/n' instead on input line 10.

LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for OML+kurier on input line 1
0.
(/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive-dist/tex/latex/kurier/omlkurier.fd
File: omlkurier.fd 2008/07/22 v0.995 font definition file for OML/kurier (MW)
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for OMS+kurier on input line 1
0.

(/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive-dist/tex/latex/kurier/omskurier.fd
File: omskurier.fd 2008/07/22 v0.995 font definition file for OMS/kurier (MW)
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for OMX+kurier on input line 1
0.

(/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive-dist/tex/latex/kurier/omxkurier.fd
File: omxkurier.fd 2008/07/22 v0.995 font definition file for OMX/kurier (MW)
) [1

{/opt/local/var/db/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] (./test.aux)

LaTeX Font Warning: Some font shapes were not available, defaults substituted.

 ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 565 strings out of 494770
 6778 string characters out of 3171404
 47256 words of memory out of 3000000
 3846 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000
 7984 words of font info for 25 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000
 134 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 23i,4n,22p,147b,113s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s
{/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive-dist/fonts/enc/dvips/cm-super/cm-super-t1.enc
}{/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive-dist/fonts/enc/dvips/kurier/mi-kurier.enc}</op
t/local/share/texmf-texlive-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb></opt
/local/share/texmf-texlive-dist/fonts/type1/public/kurier/kurierri.pfb></opt/lo
cal/share/texmf-texlive-dist/fonts/type1/public/cm-super/sfss1000.pfb>
Output written on test.pdf (1 page, 24043 bytes).
PDF statistics:
 22 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 15 compressed objects within 1 object stream
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

Comment: It doesn't happen to me, with your example.

Comment: For me neither. Show your log-file.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. Upvoting is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you.

Comment: The problem seems to be where the log file says `LaTeX Font Info:  No file OT1kurierm.fd`: the file, under the name `ot1kurierm.fd`, should be present in the same directory as `kurier.sty`. I'd suggest you to install [MacTeX](http://tug.org/mactex) rather than the (old) TeX Live provided by MacPorts.

Comment: @egreg: installing MacTeX did the job, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be a faulty installation of the `kurier` bundle: the key is in the message

```
LaTeX Font Info: No file OT1kurierm.fd
```

That file, under the name `ot1kurierm.fd`, should be present in the same directory as `kurier.sty`.

I suggest to install the current [MacTeX distribution](http://tug.org/mactex). Keep in mind that in a few days (as of today, 2012/06/25) the 2012 release of MacTeX should be available.